# Kill a process using a port (Windows/C)

Tags: windows, port

How can I kill (or just find the pid. The killing is easy) of a process that is listening on a certain port from c/c++ on Windows?

Comment: Do you know which port it will listen on? I hardly believe you can do that. I guess, you would to get all processes and find out, if they are listening on a port...

Comment: @bash.d Yes. I know which port it is listening on.